# How to set min and max values for an axis?

Tags: highcharts

I have some data that can have values in the range (0..100). Highcharts will sometimes label the axis from -10 to 110, which looks odd.

How can I prevent this? I can set a fixed `min` and `max` value for the axis, but if the current values happen to be between e.g. (50..60), I'd rather let Highcharts zoom in on the axis accordingly. Just don't want Highcharts to ever show anything outside of (0..100).

I could of course determine the appropriate `min` and `max` values myself every time I load data, but was hoping there would be some kind of `minMin` and `maxMax` setting?

Comment: I ran into the same issue recently and the only solution i found was to calculate the min/max i wanted based on the data passed in.  I just look at the data set pull out the max and give it a buffer of 10% above, and the same thing for min with a buffer of 10% below.

Comment: Highcharts doesn't have `minMin` or `maxMax` option.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like this isn't possible; opened a [feature request](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2858).

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays highcharts has [floor](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.floor) and ceiling options for this use case.